# How to split data from a single word string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, substr

I need to split data from a single word string like below,

```
$string = "RC9999999999A202";

//Need to split as follows:  

$code = "RC"; //This value must be of 2 alphabetic characters
$phone = "9999999999"; //This value must be of 10 digits
$amount = "202"; //This value can be of any length (numeric only)
```

I tried nothing because I don't have any idea regarding this since I'm a newbie.

Please help!

Please do not leave negative rating, instead try to help me.

Comment: "I tried nothing" - OK, try http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php and let us know how you get on

Comment: `[A-Z]` is an uppercase alpha between `A` and `Z`. `[0-9]` is any single number. `{}` can build a range, or number of allowed characters. `+` is a quantifier allowing one or more of the previous group/character. `*` is zero or more. Build from that. Per first var `[A-Z]{2}` would allow 2 uppercase alpa characters.

Comment: Do you really need a regex for this? Are you needing to validate that the string is in that format, or do you already know it's in that format? If that's the case, you can just take substrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match according to your specifications and populate the variables code, phone and amount.

```
$string = "RC9999999999A202";

Preg_match("/([A-Z]{2})(\d{10})A(\d+)/", $string, $match);

List($string, $code, $phone, $amount) = $match;
```

https://3v4l.org/QXVRA

This pattern assumes the "A" is always an "A".
You didn't mention it at all in the question so I assume it's always an "A".

Answer (score 1):

If your string will always be like you described **2** chars then **10** digits followed by any number of chars then you can get what you want simply using `substr` like so :

```
$string = "RC9999999999A202";

echo $code = substr($string, 0, 2); // get first 2 chars
echo $phone = substr($string, 2, 10); // get 10 chars starting from 3d char
echo $amount = substr($string, 12); // get whatever chars left
```

**Note:** this method does not validate any data, it just **extract** what you have in your string based on what you described in the question.

Comment: This doesn't confirm any of the values.. e.g. `This value must be of 2 alphabetic characters`.

Comment: I thought all he needed is to get the values no validation needed

Comment: @teeyo Use preg_match

Comment: FYI, the `strlen` isn't necessary. If you omit the third argument, `substr` will select to the end of the string by default.

Comment: I guess it is a bit unclear what the intent here is.

Comment: @Don'tPanic you’re right, thank you for mentioning that, MrProPop i’m just giving him an idea on what are the options I won’t code for him, and yes that would the best option to validate data too

Comment: Personally I flagged this question, but as this answer showed up in the review queue... maybe provide some explanation as to what this code does, and that it requires the data to be in a known format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for `preg_match`:

```
$str = 'RC9999999999A202';

if (preg_match('/([A-Z]{2})(\d{10})\D*(\d*)/', $str, $m)) {
   unset($m[0]); // delete full match from array
   print_r($m);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => RC
    [2] => 9999999999
    [3] => 202
)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gfQiwB/2)